# elasticsearch simple_query_string fields different type

Tags: elasticsearch

i am working with elasticsearch and i wnat to do this type of query
`{"query": {"simple_query_string":{"fields":["field1","field2","field3","field4"],"query":"200 100 false message"}}}`
and i have field1,field2 of type int and field3 bolean and field4 string
the problem is that elasticsearch will always return parsing error as he will try to compare for rxample field3 with 100
any working solution for this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the [Elasticsearch documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-simple-query-string-query.html), you can add a `lenient` argument at `true`, to ignore format-based errors.

Comment: thank yo,u that worked perfectly i dont know how i did not read that in the documentation

Answer (score 0):

Does it matter which field has matched the result? If not you could use [copy_to](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/copy-to.html) functionality to copy all the text to a single text field, and search on that one! Like so:

```
PUT stackoverflow
{
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "field1": {
        "type": "integer",
        "copy_to": "all_fields"
      },
      "field2": {
        "type": "integer",
        "copy_to": "all_fields"
      },
      "field3": {
        "type": "text",
        "copy_to": "all_fields"
      },
      "field4": {
        "type": "text",
        "copy_to": "all_fields"
      },
      "all_fields": {
        "type": "text"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

And the query:

```
GET stackoverflow/_search
{
  "query": {
    "simple_query_string": {
      "fields": [
        "field_all"
      ],
      "query": "200 100 false message"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: thank you for responding but i can't use that since i am not providing a mapping to elastic

Answer (score 0):

Adding a working example with index data, mapping, search query and search result

**Index Mapping:**

```
{
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "field1": {
        "type": "integer"
      },
      "field2": {
        "type": "integer"
      },
      "field3": {
        "type": "boolean"
      },
      "field4": {
        "type": "text"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**Index Data:**

```
{
  "field1": 200,
  "field2": 100,
  "field3": "false",
  "field4": "message"
}
```

**Search Query:**

```
{
  "query": {
    "simple_query_string": {
      "fields": [
        "field1",
        "field2",
        "field3",
        "field4"
      ],
      "query": "200 100 false message",
      "lenient": true
    }
  }
}
```

**Search Result:**

```
"hits": [
      {
        "_index": "66986084",
        "_type": "_doc",
        "_id": "1",
        "_score": 2.575364,
        "_source": {
          "field1": 200,
          "field2": 100,
          "field3": "false",
          "field4": "message"
        }
      }
    ]
```